# Is there an equivalent to boost::interprocess::null_mutex in C++11 (e.g. std::null_mutex)?

Tags: c++, c++11, mutex

I find the ability to drop in a `null_mutex` (currently `boost::interprocess::null_mutex`) very useful when I don't want the synchronization overhead in some cases and a real mutex in others.

I am trying to use the new c++11 `mutex` classes, but I see no equivalent for `null_mutex` - which leaves me puzzled..

Yes I know it's trivial to implement (or I can continue to use boost, but where possible I'm trying to stick the standard and seems like a small omission?)

Comment: No, there is no null mutex in the standard.

Comment: @BoPersson, not to question more smarter people than me, but any reason why (is it just too trivial..)?

Comment: I don't know, I haven't seen it proposed for the standard. That could be the actual reason why it's not there - nobody asked for it. :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can make this fairly trivially, by creating a 'null' implementation of the [`Lockable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Lockable) concept:

```
struct null_mutex
{
     void lock() {}
     void unlock() noexcept {}
     bool try_lock() { return true; }
};
```

This would work with std::lock_guard:

```
null_mutex mux;
std::lock_guard<null_mutex> guard(mux);
```

Comment: You'll also want `bool try_lock() {return true;}` to meet the Lockable requirements. All the standard lock classes and functions (even `lock_guard` for some reason) have that requirement.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I specifically implemented the minimal concept requirements: [`std::lock_guard`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard) only requires [`BasicLockable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/BasicLockable). You are right of course and I will clarify

Comment: `lock_guard` does specify `Lockable` - see 30.4.2.1/2. Maybe that's an error, since it has no conceivable reason to use `try_lock()`, but it's in the standard.

Comment: I understand it's pretty straightforward to implement, I guess there's not much demand for this, which means whoever is using this, will typically roll their own... ah well...

Comment: @MikeSeymour you're right. I read 30.4.2.1/ **1** (which is what CppReference cites). I updated my answer to be more broadly applicable :)